# jQuery code working in Firefox but fails in Chrome and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have written a jquery code for the following purpose:
There is a list of Fields, and a list of sub-fields. When user clicks on a field, the relevant subfields would be shown. Both lists are multiple-enabled `<select>`.

**HERE IS THE JS FIDDLE** (exploring it with FF it works, yet with chrome fails)

http://jsfiddle.net/mostafatalebi/WUR7F/

I use the most recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE8. This code works fine for Firefox but fails in the other two.

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="branch[]"]').change(function () {
        var $branch = $(this).children(':selected'),
            $subbranch = $('[name="subbranch[]"]').children('option');

        $subbranch.hide()

        $branch.each(function () {
            var branch = $(this).val();
            $subbranch.each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "par"+branch) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        });
    }).change();
});
```

And here is the HTML (for Mother-Fields) which the jquery is applied to:

```
<option selected value="false">Please Select the Field:</option>
<?php
    $db->where("parent", 1);
    $db->where("type", 1); // means institute
    $branches = $db->get("fields")->result_array();
    $brancc =  count($branches);
    for($i=0; $i < $brancc; $i++)
    {
        ?>
        <option class='branch-item' value="<?php echo $branches[$i]['id']; ?>" >
        <?php echo $branches[$i]['title']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
?>
</select><br />
```

And here is the HTML (Child-Fields) to which jquery is applied:

```
<select multiple class="form-option-multiple" name="subbranch[]">
<?php
    $db->where("parent", 0);
    $db->where("type", 1); // means institute
    $suboptions = $db->get("fields")->result_array();
    $suboptionscc = count($suboptions);

    for($i=0; $i < $suboptionscc; $i++) {
        ?>
        <option class='subbranch-item' id='par<?php echo $suboptions[$i]['parent_id']; ?>'
        value="<?php echo $suboptions[$i]['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $suboptions[$i]['title']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
?>
</select>
<br />
```

Both lists are initially filled with the data retrieved from Database.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"??? Error in console? Etc and etc... Please don't answer with just "it doesn't work"

Comment: it does not work and nothing happens, as if there is nothing there to be executed

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: I have edited the post. No just a yellow warning

Comment: Maybe a silly question but have you clear browser cache? The warning is just a jquery 'issue' with last chrome update but doesn't affect behaviour of your code, nothing to worry

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117819/jquery-change-isnt-working-in-chrome

Comment: Yes I have cleared the cache (ctrl+f5) which has done nothing to solve it

Comment: Then try to provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: Here is a JS field (added to the post) which exactly shows my problem

Comment: There are many issues, and they are all solved in the gist posted in my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. dozens of your subbranch-options have the same DOM id. DOM ids are supposed to be unique in the document. I've changed your code to use a class instead: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/WUR7F/1/)

   ```
   if ($(this).hasClass("par"+branch)) {
   ```
2. The problem is that you are trying to hide options in a multiselect by setting `display: none`. Both Chrome and IE do not support that. You will have to add and remove options instead.

I've build a second fiddle that does that: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/WUR7F/2/)

I added a third, invisible `select` that holds all your generated options. Whenever the user changes the branch, we clear the subbranch `select` and copy all the matching options from the hidden third into it.

Comment: what equivalent should be used instead of show() and hide()? Because remove will remove a DB-generated item. it seem I have to insert some Ajax stuff?

Comment: @Mostafa I added a second fiddle which adds and removes options as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the two instances of `.change()` first of all?
Isn't that redundant? That could be resetting your `on change` event *also*.
Because this is the real issue... rather than:

`$('select[name="branch[]"]').change(function() {})`

For compatibility, you need to use:

`$('select[name="branch[]"]').on('change', function() {})`

Here is another problem. This code needs to be moved out the `each()` it is in:

`var branch = $(this).val();`

And because the selects are multi-selects, this code will not work:

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == "par"+branch) {
    $(this).show();
}
```

Sometimes `branch` will be multiple values.

This works in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/3rzLs/

Check that out to see extreme changes needed to solve all your problems:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="branch[]"]').on('change', function() {
        var $branch = $(this).children(':selected'),
            $subbranch = $('#suboptions').children('option');

        $('[name="subbranch[]"]').empty()
        var branch = $(this).val();
        console.log( branch )

        $branch.each(function () {
            $subbranch.each(function () {
                if ( branch.indexOf( $(this).attr("id").replace("par","") )  >= 0) {
                    $('[name="subbranch[]"]').append( $(this).clone() ).show();
                }
            });
        });
    }).change();
});
```

With HTML:

Selecting on any Box of Parents' item should show a list related to the parent in Box of Children

```
<label>Box of Parents</label>

<select id="branches" class="form-option-multiple" name="branch[]" multiple="">
    <option selected="" value="false">لطفا زمینه فعالیت خود را انتخاب نمایید</option>
    <option class="branch-item" value="14">
    هنرهای دستی</option>
        <option class="branch-item" value="15">
    کامپیوتر</option>
    ...
    </select>

<!-- Then here is the second Child --><br/>

<label>Box of Parents</label>
<select size="9" multiple="" class="form-option-multiple" name="subbranch[]">
</select>

<div id="suboptions" style="display: none">
    <option style="display: none;" class="subbranch-item" id="par14" value="40">قالیبافی</option>
    <option style="display: none;" class="subbranch-item" id="par14" value="48">نقاشی</option>
    <option style="display: none;" class="subbranch-item" id="par14" value="49">گرافیک</option>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: the second change() is to trigger onchange event, nothing wrong here. BTW, your syntax has exact same behaviour as OP's code

Comment: I have done that, but it didn't solve it. I also removed the second change();

Comment: I have added a JS fiddle please check it

Comment: `.on('event', fn )` is the undeprecated syntax according to jQuery.

Definitely check out this link too then, as in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629434/chrome-bug-or-jquery-bug

Comment: I have been unable to figure out what you said. then I appreciate if you give an alternative code

Comment: I located another issue and am updating a fiddle with it fixed.